# Google Chrome 66 autoplay policy change

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, kiosk-mode

By newest update (v66.0) Google Chrome doesn't play audio/video automatically  without user's interaction.

I'm using Chrome as desktop app in **Kiosk mode** without mouse/keyboard and input at all. It just displays HTML visualization page with **sound included** and autoplayed.

Can it be avoided somehow and played by default?

In their [Autoplay Policy Changes description](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) haven't found solution.

I was also looking for some **command line switch** to include it by running Chrome and also unsuccessfully.

Comment: Since I'm having the same problem with a ChromeOS app, I was wondering: is this on ChromeOS or are you simply running Chrome in kiosk mode on another OS (e.g. Windows)?

Comment: This is Chrome app on Linux and Windows OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `chrome://flags/`, start typing `autop` in the search field, and find ...

> **Autoplay policy**
>   Policy used when deciding if audio or video is allowed to autoplay. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

The option `No user gesture is required` sounds like it should do what you want.

`chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy`

Comment: Yeah, it works by forwarding `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` command line switch.

Comment: lifesaver man! that policy is necessary to prevent abuse, but kiosk applications are a different sport

Comment: This flag was removed from settings in Chrome 76. For now the only solution seem to be the `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` command.

Comment: @MilanŠvehla but how do you pass this in andorid then?

Comment: @M.C. not sure that is at all possible. The original context of this question was a "kiosk" application using the desktop version of the browser. Those flags are passed to the executable via the command line, I doubt there even is any equivalent for that on Android.